# Why are objects considered not iterable although they actually are?

Tags: php, iterator

PHP 7.1 added the new [is_iterable](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-iterable.php) function to check whether a variable can be iterated. But although you may iterate over an objects properties `is_iterable` returns false for them.

This seems to be intentional, as it is documented and I couldn't find any PHP bugs regarding the issue but I wonder why this was done?

```
<?php
$a = new stdClass();
$a->foo = 'bar';

var_dump(is_iterable($a));

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

Outputs

```
boolean false
string 'foo' (length=3)
string 'bar' (length=3)
```

But I would expect it to output

```
boolean true
string 'foo' (length=3)
string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is true it doesn't explain why they decided to make a restrictive pseudo-type that excludes a very valid and extremely common use case.

Nowhere have I seen this topic has anyone presented a code example that can traverse an array || traversable but not an object.  This is something I'd like to see in an answer if anyone can prove this mysterious use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a question of definition, and "why is it done" is a tricky question, probably better for the PHP devs.

But some information: You can foreach over an object, and it will show the visible properies according to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

> PHP 5 provides a way for objects to be defined so it is possible to iterate through a list of items, with, for example a foreach statement. By default, all visible properties will be used for the iteration.

The `is_iterable` is checking for specific things, see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php)

> Verify that the contents of a variable is accepted by the iterable 
>   pseudo-type, i.e. that it is an array or an object implementing Traversable

An object does *not* implement `Traversable` if you don't do so yourself (and is not one of the 'other' things, like an array) so it is not "iterable" in that sence.

Long story short: foreach can iterate over anything that is iterable, but not everything that foreach can iterate over is called iterable. Its a chair-has-4-legs vs everything-with-4-legs-is-a-chair kinda issue.

I would see the fact that you can iterate over an object without explicitly implementing iterable is a sort of exception, and leave it at that. The only other anwer would be "they did it because".

Comment: Sounds about right for a PHP-related answer… meh ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: *An object does not implement Traversable if you don't do so yourself*  and  *This is an internal engine interface which cannot be implemented in PHP scripts.* from http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php. A deadlock?

Comment: @Alex Next sentence: *"Either `IteratorAggregate` or `Iterator` must be used instead."* (Note: both of those are subclasses of `Traversable`…)

Comment: I dont get the use case of excluding Objects in this check. Is there any use case where an iterable|array can be traversed when an object can not? The thing most of us wanted for a long time was a "can I foreach this" check and is_iterable does not provide this in its current state.